# Check URL is valid and belongs to specific domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using rails to build an app. The app will allow user to enter a URL into a form then save to database. (For example a URL linking to GitHub repo)

I'd like to validate the user input URL before save to ensure:

1, it's a valid URL (http, https)

2, it's actually a (200) response from this URL

3, the URL entered has the domain GitHub.com (or ensure the URL actually goes to GitHub)

Only after these are satisfied will it save to database.

So far I have:

```
class Repository < ActiveRecord::Base

Validates :url, presence: true
Validates_format_of :url, with: URI::regexp(%w(http https))

End
```

I believe I have point one covered, can anyone advise on points 2 and 3?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Net::HTTP](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTP) module.

```
uri = URI('http://example.com/some_path?query=string')

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri

  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object

  case response
    when Net::HTTPSuccess then
      # 2xx code received (success)
      response
    when Net::HTTPRedirection then
      # 3xx code received (redirected)
      location = response['location']
      warn "redirected to #{location}"
      fetch(location, limit - 1)
    else
      response.value
  end

end
```

In case it's not clear, you'd modify this sample code and include it in a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) method, and call that method like so:

```
  validate :my_custom_validation(some_uri_string)
```

Comment: You should use HEAD rather than GET, as there is no need to download the response body.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `ActiveModel::EachValidator`.

```
# app/each_validators/github_url_validator.rb
class GitHubUrlValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless valid_github_url?(value)
      record.errors.add(attribute, options[:message] || :github_url)
    end
  end

  private

  def valid_github_url?(value)
    # Check if value is valid github url here.
  end
end

class Repository < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :url, :github_url => true
end
```